# Proof that the set $\{(x_1, x_2) \in E^2: x_1>x_2\}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

(Note: $E^2$ denotes $2$-dimensional Euclidean space)

My question concerns the below "proof." Once the radius of the open ball is determined, how can it be shown that the ball contains only points in S?

Let $S \subset E^2 = \{(x_1, x_2) \in E^2: x_1>x_2\}$ .
Let the point $\ p = (x_i, x_j) \in S$. Since $x_i>x_j$, the difference $x_i-x_j$ is a positive real number. Call this $\epsilon$. Then $p$ is the center of an open ball with radius $\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$ which contains only points in S.

Comment: The function $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1 - x_2$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not a direct answer, consider working with the basis 
$$
B=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid a<b\}
$$

of $\mathbb{R}$. Then 
$$
\{B_{1}\times B_{2}\mid B_{i}\in B\}
$$

is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (in the product topology which is
the same of the topology induced on it with the euclidean norm).

In this way an open ball in the topology is a square and it would
be easier to find a square centered at $(x_{1},x_{2})\in S$ which
is contained in $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:E^1 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(x,y)=x-y$. $f$ is continuous, and $S=f^{-1}(0,\infty)$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$Note that square:

$$\{(x,y): x_i-\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}}<x<x_i+\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}};x_j-\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}}<y<x_j+\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}}\}$$

contains this ball (the ball with radius $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$).

Comment: Yes, but that square also contains points in the complement of S.

Comment: Ok, i've corrected my answer, but you need smaller radius of the ball ($\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$).